# Unable to install vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

While installing vuetify through vue add vuetify gives error .not sure what is this.Please find the error below :
Error: Cannot find module '../presets/undefined'

Comment: Navigate to your project directory, and then run this command `vue add vuetify`. If then to error occurs, try to install vuetify from vue cli, as stated in the official docs.

Comment: @YogeshKudikala :did that ,i get core-js errors now ,

Answer (score 2):

I met the similar error when adding vuetify to my **existing** vue app. The [webpack install guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#webpack-install) works for me.

> Note: I am new in Vue and Vuetify. Please let me know if I did something wrong in the following steps.

Here are some highlights:

1. Add vuetify package:

```sh
$ npm install vuetify
```

2. Create a Vuetify plugin js file e.g `plugins/vuetify.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = { /* your vuetify options*/ }

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

3. For **webpack**, you may also need to add some additional packages and add a extra config section in `webpack.config.js` (see the [webpack install guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#webpack-install)). If you are using [**parcel**](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) then you can skip this step.
4. Use it in your *entrypoint* e.g. `main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Set up your Vuetify `<v-app>` in `App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-card :elevation="2" class="mx-auto pa-6">
          <h1>Hello Vuetify from <code>{{ name }}</code></h1>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
const App = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            name: 'App'
        }
    }
}
export default App
</script>
```